# QtCreator: How to compile external source files

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have my C++ project files and want to create an additional graphical user interface for these sourcefiles. I am using windows, MVSC2012 and Qt 5.1.1 with Qt Creator 2.8.1.

So here is what i have:

My QtCreator project folder, including the following auto-generated files

```
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/main.cpp
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/mainwindow.cpp
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/mainwindow.h
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/mainwindow.ui
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/creatorProject.pro
c:/creatorProject/creatorProject/creatorProject.pro.user
```

Furthermore I the source files with the "logic" in a separated folder, e.g.

```
c:/programLogic/myFunctions.h
c:/programLogic/myFunctions.cpp
```

So I simply want to add these files to my QtCreator project so that I can e.g. include "myFunctions.h" and work with it.

**My attempt:** I used Qt Creator and added *myFunctions.h* respectively *myFunctions.cpp* by using "creatorProject >> right click >> add existing file..". After doing that my creatorProject.pro looks like this:

```
[...]
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    ../../programLogic/myFunctions.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../programLogic/myFunctions.h
```

Looks totally fine for me. Qt Creator even shows these files within the project explorer! However I have trouble using myFunctions.h within mainwindow.cpp.

```
#include "myFunctions.h" // Include can not be found
#include "../../programLogic/myFunctions.h" // Include is found but I get linker errors since myFunctions.cpp is not compiled?!
```

What is wrong within my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `INCLUDEPATH` also in your `.pro` file.

Something like:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/programLogic"
```

Comment: Neither absolute paths nor relative paths such as INCLUDEPATH += "../../programLogic/" (or even without '"'-sign) solve this problem. "#include <myFunctions.h>" or #include "myFunctions.h" result in "No such file or directory"

Comment: @Anonymous Try to delete the existing .pro.user file and then let it parse the pro file again. Also, show your entire .pro file content.

Comment: Also, delete all the previous build files.

Comment: First: If I edit the *.pro directly within the Qt Creator and save it, the Qt Creator recognizes that there are changes and parses this file again. I even re-opened the project and tried to perform a clean build. Problem persists. Here is the *.pro file:  http://codepad.org/MZGjbrDq

Comment: Do you have include guards in your header files? Try manually deleting the build folder and re-build. What is the exact error message that you get now?

Comment: Ok, "Try manually deleting the build folder and re-build." -> this was the solution. Whenever you change sth. in the *.pro file you have to delete the build folder manually. Doing this within Qt Creator does not work ("create everything new").