# QtCreator - Compiling issue - External source files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator, linker-errors

I have a Qt project, accessing another cross-platform (boost) project on my disc. Adding the header includes does not seem to cause any problem.

```
#include "../../Visual Studio 2015/Projects/..." //Header file down the road
```

Adding existing source files to the sources folder in my Qt Project works also without a problem, the files are found and I can open them. I believe the files are not correctly compiled - if at all - as I get a linker error, telling me that `%sourcefile%.obj` could not be opened. (not created)

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug\Error.obj'
```

I tried copying the content of `Error.cpp` into a new `.cpp` file created in the Qt project directory. After that the error message jumped to the next source file. I could now do this for all source files, but this seems to be quite... unhandy. Changes in the original project won't affect the Qt project then.

**Does somebody know the problem / got a solution to it ?**

I checked this [question, answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421609/qtcreator-how-to-compile-external-source-files) already, but that did not seem to fix the error or change anything.

Comment: Create a `.pri` file for your external project and include this file in your `.pro` file.

Comment: @SebastianLange Does not seem to help either. I tried creating the `.pri` file in the external project's directory and in the directory of the Qt project. Using the file in the external project seems to need the paths going from Qt project to the source files, else the files are not found. The error persists in both cases.

Comment: if you setup `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD` and `DEPENDPATH+= $$PWD` all files can be added `SOURCES+=$$PWD/error.cpp` and headers... An include is then just: `#include <error.h>`. Your pri file has to be complete and know allrequired sources. I think you are missing out some sources

Comment: I'm not missing out any source file. The error has now changed to a `LNK1181: cannot open input file 'debug\Error.obj'`, which still means that this `.obj` file is not being created. [Here is my `.pri` file, placed in the other project's directory.](http://pastebin.com/EyU65mcP) The `.pri` file is included in the `.pro` file: `include(../../Visual Studio 2015/Projects/otherProj/otherProj.pri)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple and a little strange. It appears that something is causing an issue when using paths with spaces with Qt's `include(...)` and `SOURCES` in a `*.pro` file.

```
//This apparently works and source files are compiled.
include(C:/ProjDir/ProjName.pri)

//This works too, but the source files are not being compiled.
include("../../Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ProjDir/ProjName.pri")
```

Thanks to [JKSH](https://forum.qt.io/user/jksh) on the [Qt-Forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/69108/qtcreator-compiling-issue-external-source-files/4) and [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2531178/) for his hint using a `.pri` file.